# How to load data after the DOM is loaded with axios react typescript ionic

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, axios

I am using axios to fetch data from a URL. I import axios in the module this function is in. It is a typescript file that is separated from the tsx file that contains the UI. The response is in xml:

```
export function getFornecedores(){
    console.log("Dentro do getFornecedores");
    
    axios.get(config.web_service_url + "/TM_GetEnt?pEntTp=F", {responseType: 'document'})
    .then( (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log("Axios falhou" + err))
}
```

It gives me an error Request aborted.
In my page I am doing:

```
import { IonApp, IonRouterOutlet, IonLabel, IonSelect, IonDatetime, IonSelectOption, IonInput, IonItem, IonContent, IonText, IonIcon, IonButton } from '@ionic/react';
import { logInOutline} from 'ionicons/icons';
import { Route, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { IonReactRouter } from "@ionic/react-router";
import React, {useRef, useEffect} from 'react';

import "../css/main.css";

/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
import '@ionic/react/css/core.css';

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
import '@ionic/react/css/normalize.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/structure.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/typography.css';

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
import '@ionic/react/css/padding.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/float-elements.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-alignment.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-transformation.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/flex-utils.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/display.css';

/* Theme variables */
import '../theme/variables.css';

// Components
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";

// TS Scripts
import {getFornecedores} from "../ts/validacao";

const Validacao: React.FC = () => {
    const label = useRef(null); // this is just to fire a function after the dom is loaded
    const fornecedores = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        getFornecedores();
    }, [label]);

    return(
        <IonApp>
            <Navbar page="validacao"/>

            <IonContent className="ion-padding">
                <IonItem>
                    <IonLabel ref={label} position="stacked">Fornecedores</IonLabel>
                    <IonSelect ref={fornecedores} interface="popover">
                        <IonSelectOption value="" class="brown-option">Escolha uma opção</IonSelectOption>
                    </IonSelect>
                </IonItem>

                <IonItem>
                    <IonLabel position="stacked">Tipo de documento</IonLabel>
                    <IonSelect interface="popover">
            <IonSelectOption value="" class="brown-option">Escolha uma opção</IonSelectOption>
          </IonSelect>
                </IonItem>

                <IonItem>
                    <IonLabel position="floating">Número</IonLabel>
                    <IonInput></IonInput>
                </IonItem>

                <IonItem>
                    <IonLabel position="floating">Data</IonLabel>
                    <IonDatetime displayFormat="DD MM YYYY"></IonDatetime>
                </IonItem>

                <IonButton href="/parametros" class="ion-margin-top" color="primary" expand="block">
                    Validar
                </IonButton>
            </IonContent>
        </IonApp>
    );
};

export default Validacao;
```

How can I make axios call work to populate the select with the data I receive from axios call?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you posted. So I'm not sure why the request would abort. Is the code server rendered at all?

Comment: What do you mean by code server rendered at all?

Comment: I tried doing it with ajax and I get an error too

Comment: But it works on postman

Comment: What happens if you console.log config.web_service_url

Comment: It gives me a valid url